# How can I upload photos from my Android (4.1) to Picasa without resizing to 2048 resolution?

Tags: photos, 4.1-jelly-bean, picasa

I am paying for additional storage, so the storage limit doesn't concern me.  I would like to upload full-resolution pics from my phone to my Picasa albums, but when I choose to upload a picture from my Android to a Picasa album, the picture ends up being resized to 2048 pixel max resolution.  Is there any way to disable this or bypass it without using something like Dropbox instead?

Using Nexus S running Jelly Bean.

Answer (score 1):

That is described at the Google Support page for Picasa as a limitation, even if you're currently paying for extra space, that doesn't allow you to have image files larger than 2048 pixels on their longest edge:

- Picasa and Picasa Web Albums - [Free storage limits](http://support.google.com/picasa/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1224181)

  > ### Free storage limits
  >
  > Photos up to 2048 x 2048 pixels and videos up to 15 minutes won't count towards your free storage.
  >
  > ### Automatic resizing
  >
  > All photos uploaded in Google+ will be automatically resized to 2048 pixels (on their longest edge) and won't count towards your free storage quota.
  >
  > All photos uploaded from the Picasa software or in Picasa Web Albums over the free size limit will count towards your 1 GB of free storage. When you reach your storage limit, any new photos you upload larger than the free size limit **will be automatically resized to 2048 pixels** (on their longest edge).

---

- Picasa and Picasa Web Albums - [Account upload limits](http://support.google.com/picasa/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=43879)

  > - Maximum photo size: Each image can be no larger than 20 megabytes and are restricted to 50 megapixels or less.
  > - Maximum video size: Each video uploaded can be no larger than 1GB in size.
  > - Maximum number of web albums: 10,000
  > - Maximum number of photos and videos per web album: 1,000
  > - Total storage space: Picasa Web provides 1 GB for photos and videos. Files under certain sizes don't count towards this limit.

---

You can refer to the [How Google storage plans work](http://support.google.com/picasa/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2375124), to confirm that what you pay only affects the space you have, not the service characteristics.

*As a side note: Try and talk to their customers service to work a solution.*

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  This doesn't make sense, though, because when I use the picasa program to upload the photos are not resized (so it has nothing to do with the 1GB limit).  It's only when I upload from my phone that I get trimmed to 2048 pixels.  I'm not uploading via google+ so I wouldn't think that rule would apply.

Comment: @KdawgUD Don't kill the messenger ;) You can read from Google's support page: `All photos uploaded from the Picasa software or in Picasa Web Albums ... will be automatically resized to 2048 pixels` This happens if you've already overcome the free storage of 1Gb. Follow my advice, contact their support and ask for clarification on this subject. Ps: I'll be doing the same because I agree that is an absurd limitation. :)